# Perl Script on Remote Host Returns "1" and Nothing Else

Tags: apache, perl, .htaccess

My script to check perl/CGI ability on hosted server (CGI/FastCGI provided)
only returns "1" in return_var, no more output (browser output see below):

exec pl | return_var 1 result:

exec cgi | return_var 1 result:

.htaccess is in the directory with only the 2 lines

Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl

both files .pl | .cgi got chmod 755 || output is good on local machine.

```
<?php

// PHP Version 7.0.4 | apache 5.10 Generic_142901-13 i86pc

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    echo "<br/><br/>exec pl ".exec ($cp.'perlTest.pl', $out1, $err1);echo " | return_var ".$err1;
    $result1 = join("\n", $out1)."\n";
    echo " result: ".$result1;

    echo "<br/><br/>exec cgi ".exec ($cp.'py.cgi', $out2, $err2);echo " | return_var ".$err2;
    $result2 = join("\n", $out2)."\n";
    echo " result: ".$result2;

// total output in browser is (without //):

// exec pl | return_var 1 result:
// exec cgi | return_var 1 result:  

?>
```

Comment: what do you expect your Perl script to return?

Comment: it's only to test the ability at the moment - if yes, i'll fetch the data for some gd graphic work. at the moment only #!/usr/bin/perl print "Content-type: text/html"; print("test perl\n");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the path-variable, provided by hoster

to path, received by exec(pwd)

AND deleting .htaccess out of directory, then

perlTest.pl and py.cgi will be executed.

Comment: output of altered file http://www.ube.watch/ikn.php is 

exec pl perlTest.pl | return_var 0 result: perlTest.pl

exec cgi py.cgi | return_var 0 result: Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8 cr2016.03.17 py.cgi